# LG g5 infrared red problems

Tags: lg, lg-g5

I have a LG g5 and my IR isn't working, no matter what app I use. This is my second LG g5, am I doing something wrong.. suggestions welcomed.

Comment: The LG G5 has NO IR capabilities. Why do you think it has IR?